# Может ли mysqldump сломать базу?

Tags: mysql, сервер

Появилась необходимость делать дампы MySQL базы не реже, чем раз в час (лучше - еще чаще). Планирую это делать через mysqldump, который будет запускаться кроном. База занимает всего около 300 Мб.

Вопрос: может ли mysqldump как-нибудь поломать базу?

Comment: Предположу что вы ищете pitr: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/point-in-time-recovery.html

Comment: *может ли mysqldump как-нибудь поломать базу?* Если внешнее приложение "обвалит" сервер (не mysql-сервер, а вообще), то сопутствующие повреждения файловой системы, конечно, могут поломать базу. mysqldump в подобных гадостях не замечен (за исключением случаев, когда у кого-то хватает ума загадить бэкапами весь диск с БД).

Comment: Есть подозрение, что вам нужно просто репликацию настроить вместо mysqldump

Comment: @Мелкий об этой возможности не знал, спасибо.

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за совет. Действительно, для решения этой задачи больше подходит репликация, и я в любом случае буду её реализовывать. Но сейчас мне желательно это сделать именно через mysqldump, поэтому вопрос остается открытым: может ли он поломать базу?

Comment: @Akina благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Не бойтесь, не поломает. Вот уже несколько лет использую mysqldump для регулярного резервного копирования баз. Одна БД - 230 Мб, вторая - 125.

Есть некоторые ограничения в использовании mysqldump: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-restrictions

Comment: 230 Мб это очень мало, даже на моём небольшом сервере одна база уже до двадцати гигабайт доросла)

Comment: Ну, у автора вопроса не такой размер, как у вас. С гигами лучше репликацию делать.